# how to configure environment variables for visual studio

Tags: python, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to update environment variables for VS 22 & vs code for using python and C but am unable to update it . It requires them all under same name but it fails every time. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that you have added `D:\python\Scripts\;D:\python\;D:\vs code\Microsoft VS Code\bin;` something like this...but wait, you haven't configured the user interface. Add this somewhere in list `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;` and it will work.